# How to get indices of np.amin of 3d np array?

Tags: python, numpy, min

Given the following code:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[[1, 2],
               [3, 4]],
              
              [[5, 6],
               [7, 8]], 
              
              [[3, 1],
               [1, 5]]])

x_min = np.amin(x, axis=0)
print(x_min)
```

The output (x_min) is

```
[[1 1]
 [1 4]]
```

Now I want to get the indices of dimension 0 of array x for the results of x_min array, it should be:

```
[[0 2]
 [2 0]]
```

Which function can I use to get this indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [np.argmin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html): `np.argmin(x, axis=0)`